# Warp Image to Appear in Cylindrical Projection

Tags: image, 3d, geometry, computer-vision, cylindrical

I want to warp a flat image in a way that it appears to be the projection coming from a cylinder.

I have a flat image like this:

[image: I have this flat image]

and I want to show it as something like this in 2D image:

[image: output image should be something like this]

I'm a bit phased out on geometrical projections. I visited some other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488868/opencv-wrap-image-to-cylindrical-coordinates) but I don't understand how will I represent these cylindrical coordinates (theta and rho) into x,y coordinates in cartesian (x,y) plane. Could you guys help me with an elaborative example? 
I'm coding it for iPhone and I'm not using any 3rd party library like OpenCV etc.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This is an answer in 2 parts, the math and the code

### Math

I like this problem because the projection involved is interesting but the math can still be solved by hand without too much difficulty.  To start, it is important to understand why exactly the image warps the way it does.  Say we have a flat image with a concave cylinder sitting in front of it.

[image: Demo Image 1]

The first step is to do an orthographic projection moving the image onto the curved surface.

[image: Demo Image 2]

Then those points are projected with perspective back onto the image plane.  Notice in this case that the entire image shrinks because all parts of the cylinder had a greater z coordinate than the image plane.  In your case the cylinder is touching the image plane at the left and right edges so no shrink occurs.  When the points are projected back notice they no longer form a flat line on the image plane, there is a curve because of the z coordinate of the cylinder varying with x.

[image: Demo Image 3]

The first trick is that we actually want to represent this process backwards.  You might first think that you want to take every pixel in your original image and move it into your new image.  It actually works much better if you check for every pixel in your new image where it appeared in the old image and set its colour.  That means that you need to do 3 things.

1. Set up your cylinder parameters
2. Project a ray from the camera, passing through each point in the new image and find its x,y,z coordinates on the cylinder
3. Use an orthographic projection to move that ray back to the image plane (just means drop the z component)

Keeping track of everything can be a little tricky so I will try to use consistent terminology.  First of all, I am assuming that you want to guarantee that your cylinder touches your image at the edges.  If that is true, then the the 2 free parameters you can choose are cylinder radius and focal length.

The equation of a circle in the zx plane is

```
x^2+(z-z0)^2 = r^2
```

assuming the center of the circle lies on the z axis.  If the edge of the cylinder is going to touch the edge of the image plane which has a width w and a focal length f then

```
omega^2+(f-z0)^2 = r^2 //define omega = width/2, it cleans it up a bit
z0 = f-sqrt(r^2-omega^2)
```

Now we know all the parameters of the cylinder we move on to step 2, project lines from the camera, through the image plane at xim to the cylinder at xc.  Here is a quick diagram of the terminology.

[image: Demo4]

We know the line we are projecting starts at the origin and crosses the image plane at xim.  We can write its equation as

```
x = xim*z/f
```

Since we want the x coordinate when it passes through the cylinder combine the equations

```
xim^2*z^2/f^2 + z^2 - 2*z*z0 +z0^2 - r^2 = 0
```

You can use the quadratic equation to solve for z and then plug back into the line equation to get x.  The two solutions correspond to the two places the line touches the circle, since we are only interested in the one that happens after the image plane, and that one will always have a larger x coordinate, use -b + sqrt(...).  Then

```
xc = xim*z/f;
yc = yim*z/f;
```

The final step of removing the orthographic projection is easy just drop the z component and you are done.

### Code

I know you said you are not using openCV but I am going to use it in my demonstration as an image container.  All the operations are done on a pixel by pixel basis so it should not be hard for you to convert this to work on whatever image container you are using.  First I made a function which converts from image coordinates in the final image to coordinates in the original image.  OpenCV puts its image origin at the top left which is why I start by subtracting w/2 and h/2 and end by adding them back in

```cpp
cv::Point2f convert_pt(cv::Point2f point,int w,int h)
{
    //center the point at 0,0
    cv::Point2f pc(point.x-w/2,point.y-h/2);

    //these are your free parameters
    float f = w;
    float r = w;

    float omega = w/2;
    float z0 = f - sqrt(r*r-omega*omega);

    float zc = (2*z0+sqrt(4*z0*z0-4*(pc.x*pc.x/(f*f)+1)*(z0*z0-r*r)))/(2* (pc.x*pc.x/(f*f)+1)); 
    cv::Point2f final_point(pc.x*zc/f,pc.y*zc/f);
    final_point.x += w/2;
    final_point.y += h/2;
    return final_point;
}
```

Now all that is left is to sample every point in the new image at the old image.  There are many ways of doing this and I do the simplest one I know of here, bilinear interpolation.  Also this is only set up to work on greyscale, making it work on colour is simple just apply the process to all 3 channels.  I just thought it would be a bit clearer this way.

```cpp
for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        cv::Point2f current_pos(x,y);
        current_pos = convert_pt(current_pos, width, height);

        cv::Point2i top_left((int)current_pos.x,(int)current_pos.y); //top left because of integer rounding

        //make sure the point is actually inside the original image
        if(top_left.x < 0 ||
           top_left.x > width-2 ||
           top_left.y < 0 ||
           top_left.y > height-2)
        {
            continue;
        }

        //bilinear interpolation
        float dx = current_pos.x-top_left.x;
        float dy = current_pos.y-top_left.y;

        float weight_tl = (1.0 - dx) * (1.0 - dy);
        float weight_tr = (dx)       * (1.0 - dy);
        float weight_bl = (1.0 - dx) * (dy);
        float weight_br = (dx)       * (dy);

        uchar value =   weight_tl * image.at<uchar>(top_left) +
        weight_tr * image.at<uchar>(top_left.y,top_left.x+1) +
        weight_bl * image.at<uchar>(top_left.y+1,top_left.x) +
        weight_br * image.at<uchar>(top_left.y+1,top_left.x+1);

        dest_im.at<uchar>(y,x) = value;
    }
}
```

Here is a sample output for f = w/2 and r = w.

[image]

Comment: In the code where you are calculating zc=... that has something missing after the last integer value of 2

Comment: Also, I think I couldn't specify earlier that 4 of my images will make 360 degrees of a cylinder. That is, each image will cover 90 degrees of the cylinder's curvature.

Comment: Another elaboration: The camera is supposed to be located at the center of the cylinder. (Center being vantage point, so we pan the camera and view the 360 degree panorama in 4 images). So length of the ray from camera will aways equal the radius. Could you please reflect or modify answer as per this elaboration?

Comment: @Usman.3D the line of code that calculates zc is float zc = (2*z0+sqrt(4*z0*z0-4*(pc.x*pc.x/(f*f)+1)*(z0*z0-r*r)))/(2 (pc.x*pc.x/(f*f)+1)); and is not missing anything in the posted answer.

Comment: @Usman.3D What exactly are you trying to do?  This sounds like a different question.  Are you trying to stitch a panorama together forming 360 degrees?  If so, I think you can do it with the code I posted above just by specifying f and r such that the 4 image planes form the inscribed square of the cylinder.  The issue is that if you are making a panorama from a real scene your focal length is no longer arbitrary, you used a real camera on a real scene.  That is why I think it may be a separate question from the one you asked here.

Comment: I think the line was missing multiplication sign * after the integer value 2. So I guess the correct line is: float zc = (2*z0+sqrt(4*z0*z0-4*(pc.x*pc.x/(f*f)+1)*(z0*z0-r*r)))/(2* (pc.x*pc.x/(f*f)+1));____ About Panorama, my task is to present the 360 degrees shot panorama into 4 cubic faces. These 4 cubic faces are fed to HTML5 based code and it shows the panorama by automatically arranging the 4 images next to each other. The issu was that, the images required by this code are not flat but cylindrical projection, hence my question. :) Now I think I have resolved much with your help.

Comment: So the second image I posted, that was the image which HTML5 code uses along with 3 similar images. I played around and set the f=w/2 and cylindrical warping does change its shape. The concept of orthogonal and perspective projections is understood, but I think I lacked the understanding on math. Maybe I'll have to spend more time on it. Nevertheless the task seems to be complete. I'll update you if there's still any issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Usman.3D You are completely correct.  I have no idea how I dropped the 2*, I thought I just pasted it in.  Good luck

Comment: @Hammer will you provide me the class for converting image in Cylindrical shape?

Comment: @Hammer Could you tell me how to do the same with opencv apis. Or please check my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054723/warping-opencv-for-image-display-to-curved-screen-with-visual-studio)