# Warp Image on a convex cylindrical projection in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, image-processing, opencv

I want to warp an image on a convex cylindrical projection.

I found this question:

[Warp Image to Appear in Cylindrical Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017790/warp-image-to-appear-in-cylindrical-projection)

This solves the problem with an concave cylindrical projection.

I want this to be in convex cylindrical projection.

Can someone tell me how to do this in using OpenCV or any other framework

Comment: Your image is going to bulge.  That means that either the center vertical strip of your image will grow and move off the screen or the edges of your image will shrink.  Which do you prefer?

Comment: http://www.zazzle.com/chocolate_cup_cake_in_a_mug_recipe-168019029644370943                                                .....I have two images...one picked from the gallery and the other image is that of a mug.....i want to have the output as it is given in this link

Comment: In that image the camera is not centered on the cylinder it is also slightly above and looking down, do you want to be able to do that as well?