# Warping : Opencv for image display to curved screen with visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'm trying to use opencv APIs to warp image so that to dispaly it to a curved screen.
I have gone through the warping apis provided in opencv [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/stitching/doc/warpers.html).

But all APIS require the camera calibration matrix(K) and the rotation matrix(R).

But my images does not depend on a camera as im not correcting any distortion.

So can someone help me how achieve this kind of warping so that image can be better displayed on a curved screen.

I am using visual studio with opencv library in C++.

My input image will be like this [image]

and output needs to like this [image]

And i have to use opencv apis.

The above shape I have achieved through the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017790/warp-image-to-appear-in-cylindrical-projection)

Please give some suggestions.....

Comment: Could you provide image samples (input --> output) of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Berriel my requirement is similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017790/warp-image-to-appear-in-cylindrical-projection) question. But using opencv apis.

Comment: I have tried using the cylindrical warper class of opencv with some sample K and R values which got from net and played around some time but i could not achive the shape as given in the above link.

Comment: did you solve your problem kevin

Comment: @AqeelHaider no man, i did not get.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12017790/warp-image-to-appear-in-cylindrical-projection